# Pass through list of properties as a parameter

Tags: c#

Looking to pass through a list of properties of a class which are then read for the custom attribute held against each property passed through:

```
class Foo 
{
    [FooBar(Name="Prop1")]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [FooBar(Name="Prop2")]
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    [FooBar(Name="Prop3")]
    public bool Prop3 { get; set; }
}

// unsure of the props parameter type here
public List<string> GetAttr(Expression<List<Func<Foo, object>>> props)
{
    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        // get FooBar attributes name value of the properties passed in
    }
}
```

This is then referenced along the lines of this:

```
GetAttr(bar => { bar.Prop1, bar.Prop2 });
```

which would return:

```
"Prop1", "Prop2"
```

I've managed to get it working by defining the parameter as a params Expression>> but this ends up very verbose as the bar reference needs to be specified each time:

```
GetAttr(bar => bar.Prop1, bar => bar.Prop2);
```

While this works it's more verbose than the system I'm trying to replace.

The intention is to be able to specify the properties that are returned in the list

Edit:
Added in another property to sample code.

Comment: Is reflection an option?

Comment: yes, because it will be a generic method where any class will be passed in, reflection will most likely be needed @mahlatse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code?

My idea is creating an extension of `Type` to get the value of the attributes for each property. The method receives an expression containing all properties you want to fetch their values.

```
 public static TValue[] GetAttributeValue<TClass, TAttribute, TValue>(
        this Type type,
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector,
        Expression<Func<TClass, object>> properties)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var rs = new List<TValue>();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

        //find the name of properties in the expression
        MemberExpression body = properties.Body as MemberExpression;
        var fields = new List<string>();
        if (body == null)
        {
            NewExpression ubody = properties.Body as NewExpression;
            if (ubody != null)
                foreach (var arg in ubody.Arguments)
                {
                    fields.Add((arg as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
                }
        }

        //get attributes of the properties allowed
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (!fields.Contains(prop.Name))
                continue;

            var att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(
           typeof(TAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
            if (att != null)
            {
                rs.Add(valueSelector(att));
            }                
        }           
        return rs.ToArray();
    }
```

and use like this:

```
 var rs = typeof(Foo).GetAttributeValue((FooBar fb) => fb.Name, (Foo p) => new { p.Prop1, p.Prop2 });
```

Comment: Nice solution, but can't use this, as this returns all the properties, not the ones targeted. Sorry should've specified that in the questions, will update

Comment: This now has the issue I'm trying to get away from which is refactoring protection. In the answer you've spcified the array of strings as properties to retrieve. But if I rename Prop2 -> prop22 then the functionality breaks

Comment: Thanks. It can give me more motivation with a upvote. :)